# Node.js and SQLite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am want to create web server that will return data for my mobile app. I use Node.js for server and SQLite3 for database. I created method that must return data from sql, but I don't know how to do it correctly. As I know all methods from SQLite lib are async so I have no idea how to do sync request for DB. I tried this way:

```
app.get('/getAllLeagues',function (req, res) {
  console.log("get")
  var obj = db.all("SELECT name FROM Leagues")
})
```

But seems that obj is still the same as db object

Comment: Why would you want to do it synchronously?

Comment: I don't know what `db.all` looks like, but odds are it takes a callback as another parameters in which you would `res.send(results)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your app is an express server instance or similar. The database query function takes a callback function that is called once the queried rows are ready or an error is found.

```
app.get('/getAllLeagues',function (req, res) {
  console.log("get")
  var obj = db.all("SELECT name FROM Leagues",
    function(err, rows) {
        res.type('json');
        res.send(rows);
    });
});
```

For simplicity, there is no error handling. It is better to try..catch a similar request to avoid crashing your app in case the database or the table is not found.